# Yosemite - Make Safari tab font bold or bigger

Tags: safari, font

I’ve updated my system to Yosemite and now I wonder if there’s a way to increase tab font size (or make it bold).

Answer (score -1):

As Yosemite user, I understand your problem. What you could try to do to improve readability is to install good old Lucida Grande font as system: 
[project page on Github](https://github.com/schreiberstein/lucidagrandeyosemite)

It worked fine for me.

Comment: Please provide the information here and not in a link